# renaming tab using the php sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

im trying to rename a tab using the php sdk but im getting this error

**Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Tab '591882604157641' does not exist on profile 216407665045740 thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1028**

**216407665045740** is a valid page
**591882604157641** is tab and is correctly installed on that page!

http://www.facebook.com/pages/My-test-page/216407665045740?id=216407665045740&sk=app_591882604157641

this is what im doing:

1. i get the token for the page and save the user token for later use. (manage_pages permissions is granted)
2. update the tab name
3. set the user token back

and this is the code:

```
$page_id = $signed_request['page']['id'];

$user_access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$page_access_token = $facebook->api("/{$page_id}?fields=access_token");
$page_access_token = $page_access_token['access_token'];

if($facebook->setAccessToken($page_access_token))
{
    $facebook->api("/{$page_id}/tabs/591882604157641", 'POST', array(
        'custom_name' => 'another test name'
    ));
}

$facebook->setAccessToken($user_access_token);
```

i tried everything but im stucked here!! thx a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the way of renaming a tab.

```
$facebook->api("/{$page_id}/tabs/app_591882604157641", 'POST', array(
 'custom_name' => 'another test name'
));
```

just adding *app_* before the app id!

Answer (score 0):

```
      $page_id = $signed_request['page']['id'];

     $user_access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

     $page_access_token = $facebook->api("/{$page_id}?fields=access_token");

     $page_access_token = $page_access_token['access_token'];

     if($facebook->setAccessToken($page_access_token))
     {
        $facebook->api("/{$page_id}/tabs/app_591882604157641", 'POST', array(
            'custom_name' => 'another test name'
     ));
     }

     $facebook->setAccessToken($user_access_token);
```

Works Perfectly fine